# TFS query to get Work Items created by a few users

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to create a TFS query to show all the Work Items of type "Issue" & "Requirement" created by person "A" & "B".

I have the below query but it doesn't give me the expected results:

[image: TFS query]

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181360(v=vs.90).aspx

Thank you !

Adding details as suggested in the comments by @ios82

The main thing I had to do was to use the "grouped clauses" as described in the link above.

You do that by selecting the parameters you want to group by, right clicking and selecting the option of "Group Clauses". Screenshot below.

[image]

In my case I grouped both the "work item type" clauses together & the "created by". clauses together.
Also, the Condition on the CreatedBy (B) Should be changed to "OR" instead of "AND". That did it !!

Answer (score 6):

Change the Created By clauses to "Or" and grouping them together. That should give you your expected results. Like this:

[image]